# CMake Toolchain file for Buildroot with external toolchain

Tags: cmake, toolchain, buildroot

I have generated a toolchain with buildroot using the **make sdk** command. This toolchain is able to relocate and I used it as external toolchain in buildroot. When using the internal toolchain, a file called **output/host/share/buildroot/toolchainfile.cmake** is used in my cmake project.

The idea behind generating an external toolchain is to not generate it all the time. All my configured target packages go inside the toolchain sysroot but when I make changes to the target package constellation, my cmake project will never notice due to the fact that the sysroot from the toolchain is used and not from the compiled buildroot sysroot.

Is there anyone facing the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the sysroot folder and it seems that buildroot copies the selected target packages into the that folder. So the toolchain is modified on every build unless you reinstall the external toolchain. So every change on the target package configuration will go into the toolchain and your project will see all updated packages.